# How to implement equation amnog two raster grid cells ( Calculate average wind using u and v wind components on each grid cells)

Tags: r, raster, equation, netcdf, r-raster

I have two raster stack files `ur` and `vr` with u and v component of wind speed respectively.
How can I calculate average wind speed and direction in each grid cell ?
I know I can calculate wind direction using following equation

```
windir<-calc(atan2(vwind, uwind) * 360/2/pi) + 180
```

and average wind using

```
winav<- ((mean.u^2 + mean.v^2)^0.5)
```

My problem is how can I implement these equations on each grid cells of `ur` and `vr`
 I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484558/how-to-calculate-wind-direction-from-u-and-v-wind-components-in-r) and other links however still stocked in this calculation.

Comment: Note that calculating an average wind direction is not that straightforward. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44621/calculate-average-wind-direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `RasterStack`s `vr` and `ur`

```
vr <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
ur <- flip(vr, 'y')
```

You can indeed use your formulas:

```
windir <- atan2(vr, ur) * 180/pi + 180

winav <- (ur^2 + vr^2)^0.5
```

Alternatively, you can use `overlay`

```
windir2 <- overlay(vr, ur, fun=function(x,y) atan2(x,y) *180/pi + 180)

winav2 <- overlay(vr, ur, fun=function(x, y) (x^2 + y^2)^0.5 )
```